# Making a list based off of list of months in Python

Tags: python, list, for-loop, count, append

I am using Python to make lists. Should be easy! I don't know why I'm struggling so much with this.

I have some data that I am counting up by date. There is a date column like this:

```
Created on
5/1/2015
5/1/2015
6/1/2015
6/1/2015
7/1/2015
8/1/2015
8/1/2015
8/1/2015
```

In this case, there would be 2 Units created in May, 2 Units in June, 1 Unit in July, and 3 Units in August.

I want to reflect that in a list that starts in April ([April counts, May counts, June counts, etc...]):

```
NumberofUnits = [0, 2, 3, 1, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

I have a nice list of months

```
monthnumbers

Out[69]: [8, 5, 6, 7]
```

I also have a list with the `unitcounts = [2, 3, 1, 3]` I got this using value_counts.

So it's a matter of making a list of zeroes and replacing parts with the unitcount list, right?

For some reason all of my tries are either not making a list or making a list with one zero in it.

```
NumberofUnits = [0]*12

for i in range(0,len(monthnumbers)):
    if  **monthnumbers[i] == (i+4):** **This part is wrong**       
        NumberofUnits.append(unitcounts[i])
        s = slice(0,i+1)
```

I also tried

```
NumberofUnits = []
for i in range(0, 12):
    if len(NumberofUnits) > i:
        unitcounts[i:]+unitcounts[:i]
        NumberofUnits.append(unitcounts[i])
        s = slice(0,i+1)
    else:
        unitcounts.append(0)
```

But this doesn't account for the fact that in this round my data starts with May, so I need a zero in the first slot.

Comment: There are only two entries from May.

Answer (score 1):

You can count entries using `collections.counter`

```
from collections import Counter

lines = ['5/1/2015', '5/1/2015', ..., '8/1/2015']
month_numbers = [int(line.split("/")[0]) for line in lines]

cnt = Counter(month_numbers)
```

If you already have counts you can replace above with

```
from collections import defaultdict

cnt = defaultdict(int, zip(monthnumbers, unitcounts))
```

and simply map to entries with (month_number - offset) mod 12:

```
[x[1] for x in sorted([((i - offset) % 12, cnt[i]) for i in range(1, 13)])]
```

Answer (score 1):

If the data is coming from a file or any iterable you can use an `OrderedDict`, creating the keys in order starting from `4/april`, then increment the count for each month you encounter the finally print the list of values at the end which will be in the required order:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

od = OrderedDict((i % 12 or 12, 0) for i in range(4, 16))
# -> OrderedDict([(4, 0), (5, 0), (6, 0), (7, 0), (8, 0), (9, 0), (10, 0), (11, 0), (12, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (3, 0)])

with open("in.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        mn = int(line.split("/",1)[0])
        od.setdefault(mn, 0)
        od[mn] += 1

print(list(od.values()))
[0, 2, 2, 1, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Unless you do the logic like above, associating the data when you actually  parse it then it is going to be a lot harder figure out what count is for which month. Creating the association straight away is a much simpler approach.

If you have a list, tuple etc.. of values the logic is exactly the same:

```
 for dte in list_of_dates:
        mn = int(dte.split("/",1)[0])
        od.setdefault(mn, 0)
        od[mn] += 1
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am confused though, what is in your in.text file?

Comment: @jenryb, I just used the dates from your question, it does not matter where they come from the logic is exactly the same, just iterate over the dates and apply it

Comment: Thanks. This worked and cut out tons of unnecessary counting code I attempted before.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just:

```
counter = [0]*12
for m in monthnumbers:
   counter[(m - 4) % 12] += 1

print counter
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is a more "old school" approach. It assumes your dates are in the first column of your CSV file, i.e. `cols[0]`. It validates the input dates, it will raise a ValueError exception if a date is not valid or if it is older than the last one. It will also cope if your input skips one or more months.

```
import csv
from datetime import datetime

with open("input.csv", "r") as f_input:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input)
    header = next(csv_input)
    last_date = datetime(year=2015, month=4, day=1)
    cur_total = 0
    units_by_month = []

    for cols in csv_input:
        cur_date = datetime.strptime(cols[0], "%m/%d/%Y")

        if cur_date.month == last_date.month:
            cur_total += 1
        elif cur_date < last_date:
            raise ValueError, "Date is older"
        else:
            extra_months = ((cur_date.month + 12 - last_date.month) if cur_date.year - last_date.year else (cur_date.month - last_date.month)) - 1
            units_by_month.extend([cur_total] + ([0] * extra_months))
            last_date = cur_date
            cur_total = 1

    units_by_month.extend([cur_total] + [0] * ((8-len(units_by_month)) if len(units_by_month) < 9 else 0))
    print units_by_month
```

So for your input it will give the following output:

```
[0, 2, 2, 1, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

If one extra entry was added `3/1/2016`, the following would be displayed:

```
[0, 2, 2, 1, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
```